# Reflecting a database in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an existing database that I want to reflect into my flask application so I can interact with the database. I can reflect the database but then am unsure how to declare the classes representing the tables in my code.

I have done a lot of searching around stackoverflow and other sources including SQLAlchemy and flask-SQLAlchemy but answers are a bit to advanced for me.

The following code works.

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///.../app.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    db.reflect(bind='__all__', app=None)
    model = db.Model
    meta = db.metadata
    engine = db.engine

    print(db.get_tables_for_bind())
```

But I am not sure how to get from the above code to classes. For example the print statement above shows tables User and Post exist. But if I append the following code it says User and Post are undefined.

```
u1 = User(username='john', email='john@example.com')
p1 = Post(body="post from john",author=u1,timestamp=now + timedelta(seconds=1))
```

Here is the output from the print statement.

```
[
Table('alembic_version', MetaData(bind=None), Column('version_num', VARCHAR(length=32), table=<alembic_version>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), schema=None), 

Table('followers', MetaData(bind=None), Column('follower_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<followers>), Column('followed_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<followers>), schema=None), 

Table('user', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<user>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('username', VARCHAR(length=64), table=<user>), Column('email', VARCHAR(length=120), table=<user>), Column('password_hash', VARCHAR(length=128), table=<user>), Column('about_me', VARCHAR(length=140), table=<user>), Column('last_seen', DATETIME(), table=<user>), Column('last_message_read_time', DATETIME(), table=<user>), schema=None), 

Table('message', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<message>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('sender_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<message>), Column('recipient_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<message>), Column('body', VARCHAR(length=140), table=<message>), Column('timestamp', DATETIME(), table=<message>), schema=None), 

Table('notification', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<notification>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('name', VARCHAR(length=128), table=<notification>), Column('user_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<notification>), Column('timestamp', FLOAT(), table=<notification>), Column('payload_json', TEXT(), table=<notification>), schema=None), 

Table('post', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<post>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('body', VARCHAR(length=140), table=<post>), Column('timestamp', DATETIME(), table=<post>), Column('user_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<post>), Column('language', VARCHAR(length=5), table=<post>), schema=None), 

Table('task', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', VARCHAR(length=36), table=<task>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('name', VARCHAR(length=128), table=<task>), Column('description', VARCHAR(length=128), table=<task>), Column('user_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=<task>), Column('complete', BOOLEAN(), table=<task>), schema=None)
]
```

Can someone indicate how I declare the classes corresponding to the tables in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a **.py** file to define your model (e.g - models.py)
And import the db into the file **change path.to.file to actual location**

*models.py*

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Unicode
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer

from path.to.file import db


class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'User'

    rid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(Unicode(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False, unique=True)


class Post(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Post'

    rid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.rid', ondelete='cascade'), nullable=False)
    body = Column(Unicode(500), nullable=False, unique=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```

Now you can import the User and Post model something like

```
from ./models import User
from ./models import Post

u1 = User(username='john', email='john@example.com')
p1 = Post(body="post from john",author=u1,timestamp=now + timedelta(seconds=1))
```

Hopefully, that may help you

Comment: Hi Ashish, yes I am aware of that but the point is I have reflected the actual database into SQLAlchemy so User and Post should have been made available automatically, but I just don't know how to bind to them. What you have typed above is already in  db.get_tables_for_bind()  but how do i bind?

Comment: Could you please also show the output of db.get_tables_for_bind().

Comment: Hi Ashish, i have added the output of the print statement to my question.

Comment: Close analysis shows the Table items above are SQLAlchemy table objects. There is a package called sqlacodegen that converts this into the python code that can represent a model as per the typical flask-SQLAlchemy coding practices, thereby enabling the u1=User usage. I am still hoping there is a way to dynamically declare these classes in code?

Answer (score -1):

In order to use a reflected table in a query with SQLAlchemy, you should establish a variable to be a reference to the table itself.

E.g. considering the `followers` table, this would translate to do something like this:

```py
followers = metadata.tables['followers']
```

you can now query it like this

```py
from sqlalchemy import select
s = select([followers]).limit(10)
engine.execute(s).fetchall()
```

This is explained in detail in the book Essential SQLAlchemy (2nd ed) by Jason Myers and Rick Copeland (O'Reilly), at page 66.

Bonus: [the sample code](https://github.com/oreillymedia/essential-sqlalchemy-2e/blob/master/ch05/CH05.ipynb) used to illustrate the concept in the book itself